# Material-UI ThemeProvider overwrites styles globally instead of only for wrapped components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themeprovider

I have a React Component with multiple Material-UI Selects. Now I wanted to overwrite some styles of **one of them** so I created a theme and now want to apply it wit the ThemeProvider.
My problem is that the ThemeProvider overwrites the styles of every Select and not only of the one it is wrapped around.

When googling I found a lot of questions how to make ThemeProvider apply its overwrites globally but that is the opposite of what I am trying to do. **I want the ThemeProvider to apply its overwrites only to the Components, that it wraps around.**
Is there a better alternative to using ThemeProvider in my usecase? If yes, it has to work with class based Components (because I am using one here)

Codesandbox that shows my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-sun-vyl9i

I am fairly new to Material-UI, so forgive me if I do something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I think in that case, it might be better to give a custom `classes` object to the `Select` component with all the styles you want to overwrite. You can refer [Button override classes example Material UI](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes) for reference

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution myself. According to this [issue on the material-ui github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15914) , there is a `v4` bug that multiple `ThemeProviders` must have a parent `ThemeProvider` element. According to them it will be fixed in the upcoming `v5`.

So what I did, I just wrapped a `<ThemeProvider>` around my `<div className="App">` without giving it a `theme` prop.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer so the thread will be closed as soon as I can (in 2 days)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in V4 and had to resolve it another way.

The parent `<ThemeProvider>` with no `theme` prop solution wouldn't work with Typescript because the `theme` prop is required.

If anyone needs a solution that works with Typescript, I resolved it using `StylesProvider`. By wrapping each `ThemeProvider` in a `StyleProvider` with a different seed, your theme will no longer interfere with any other components outside of the `StyleProvider`.
Like so

```
import { ThemeProvider, StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
//...
 <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <children>
      </ThemeProvider>
  </StylesProvider>
```

You'll want to create a `generateClassName` prop to pass in:

```
import { createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  seed: 'blue-select,
});

export default generateClassName;
```